# Correctly returning from SecondActivity to MainActivity using Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an app with two activties. One is `MainActivity`, where i call the `Intent` to the `SecondActivity`. Then, on the second sreen I create an Object, that I would like to return to `MainActivity`. I create an `Intent` from `SecondActivity` to `MainActivity` and put this object there. The question is where should I recieve this `Intent` in `MainActivity` code? I've tried implementing `onResume()` methods just to see what happens, but in this case it runs both `onCreate()` and `onResume()` methods upon returning to the main screen. Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: you can use this library for easy intent creation between activities: https://github.com/kostasdrakonakis/android_navigator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your MainActivity call the SecondActivity using startActivityForResult() method

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

In your SecondActivity set the data which you want to return back to MainActivity

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("result",result);//Data you want to send back
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
finish();
```

Now in your MainActivity class write following code for the onActivityResult() method.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            String result=data.getStringExtra("result");
        }
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            //Write your code if there's no result
        }
    }
}//onActivityResult
```

Check this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) for more about onActivityResult;

Answer (score 0):

1) There are two ways, first one the way you are doing.
In that case you can receive the `Intent` in any life cycle of Android i.e. `onCreate`, `onStart`, `onResume`, depending upon the requirement of your app. In normal case we use `getIntent().getExtras()` in `onCreate`.

2) But for this scenario, I would like to recommend you to use `startActivityForResult()` instead of `startActivity()`, because in this case you don't have to finish `MainActivity` while creating `SecondActivity`, and just return your intent before finishing `SecondActivity`. Also note that there is no need to create `MainActivity` again, but get your `Intent` data in the call back `onActivityResult`.